# Where can I get test sequences for HEVC?

Tags: dataset, sequence, hevc, video-compression

I need the HEVC test video sequences. If anyone can help me how to get the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

They are stored here: ftp://ftp.ient.rwth-aachen.de/ctc/

To get the credentials, you may contact JCTVC or JVET chairs Gary Sullivan or Jens R. Ohm.
If they didn't answer, you may ask someone from your country's National Body (NB).

(I do have them, but I'm afraid I'm not supposed to disclose it here.)